# Will not line up

Tags: html, css

My search button will not line up with my search bar. Can anyone please help me figure out why. I have tried everything I know how to do. I also asked others and it seems no one can help me. I am sure it is an easy fix just im new and can not figure it out at all. Thanks for any and all help..

```css
.tftextinput4 {
background: #ffffff;
border-top: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
border-left: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
border-bottom: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
border-right: 0px solid #e4e4e4;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
border-top-left-radius: 50px;
color: #000000;
float: center;  
font-size: 21px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 45px;
margin-top: 40px;
padding: 10px 5px;
text-indent: 10px;
width: 700px;
}
 
.tfbutton4 {
background: white url(https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/2/images/main/searchbutton.png) left center no-repeat;
background-color: #ffffff;
background-position: 10px;
border-top: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
border-left: 0px solid #e4e4e4;
border-bottom: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
border-right: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
border-top-right-radius: 50px;
color: #ffffff;
cursor: pointer; 
font-weight: 400;  
height: 69px;
margin-left: -4px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
width: 45px;  
}

.tfbutton4:hover {
background: white url(https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/2/images/main/searchbutton.png) left center no-repeat;
background-color: #ffffff;
background-position: 10px;
border-top: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
border-left: 0px solid #e4e4e4;
border-bottom: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
border-right: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
border-top-right-radius: 50px;
color: #ffffff;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: 400;  
height: 69px;
margin-left: -4px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
width: 45px;  
}
 
.tfclear {
clear:both;
}
```

```html
<form class="tfnewsearch" action="http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=" method="get">
<input type="text" id="tfq" class="tftextinput4" name="q"  size="21" maxlength="12000" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['q'])) echo " value='{$_REQUEST['q']}'"?> autocomplete="off" placeholder="Safe Web Search...">
<input type="submit" value="" class="tfbutton4">
</form>
<div class="tfclear"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "will not line up"? What are you trying to line it up with? Are you trying to get it all on one line?

Comment: There is no such property as `float:center`...to start with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well there are two reasons why you are not getting as you expect.

1. You do not have `margin-top` for your submit button like you have for search field.
2. As both(`inputs`) are `inline-block` type of `display` elements. They need `vertical-align` to be as `middle`.

**So doing so will solve your issue.**

## Snippet :

```css
.tftextinput4 {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-top: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-left: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-right: 0px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  color: #000000;
  /*float: center; REMOVED THIS AS IT's INVALID*/
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-indent: 10px;
  width: 700px;
  max-width:calc(100% - 57px); /*ADDED THIS so it will never exceed 100%*/
  vertical-align: middle; /*ADDED THIS LINE*/
}

.tfbutton4 {
  background: white url(https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/2/images/main/searchbutton.png) left center no-repeat;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-position: 10px;
  border-top: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-left: 0px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-right: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 69px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 45px;
  margin-top: 40px; /*ADDED THIS LINE*/
  vertical-align: middle; /*ADDED THIS LINE*/
}

.tfbutton4:hover {
  background: white url(https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/2/images/main/searchbutton.png) left center no-repeat;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-position: 10px;
  border-top: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-left: 0px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-right: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 69px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 45px;
}

.tfclear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<form class="tfnewsearch" action="http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=" method="get">
  <input type="text" id="tfq" class="tftextinput4" name="q" size="21" maxlength="12000" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Safe Web Search...">
  <input type="submit" value="" class="tfbutton4">
</form>
<div class="tfclear"></div>
```

Hopes this helps you out.

Cheers!